Chessboard Domination by too few queens?
I am looking for patterns of Domination by Independent queens - one source says there is a pattern for 7x7 with only 4 queens with no queens attacking another ie independent.  I cannot find it so far.
The pattern for 'complete domination' is easily available but I am interested in outcomes for FEWER queens and how much they can dominate.  Beyond 11x11 it seems likely that 6Q and 7Q may require odd or asymmetric patterns to be maximal.  I can supply notes and diagrams if required.

Notes and diagrams would be nice. What does domination mean?

I assume what you mean by 'Domination' is that all squares are hit, and by 'Independent' you mean that no queen sees eachother?

$(1,3), (4,5), (6,2)$ and $(7,7)$ should do the trick.

strangely 2,1 seems to be outstanding for that arrangement;  22,34,61,74 does succeed with all 7x7 covered and no queens attacking another.     Dominant is that the whole area is covered;  independent means no queen attacks another.

Error in previous entry - coverage is by 22,35,61,74 ooops.
The 2-queen structure ie Maximum squares covered  x,x,x,15,23,30,37,44,52,60,68 etc has been proposed to OEIS.com as #A374933;  3-queen, 4-queen will follow.
